# Access parent attribute from child (python)

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a base class with an attribute that I need to access and manipulate from two child classes.
When I try to access the attribute through BaseClass.attribute I get an Attribute error.

If I access the attribute through self.attribute in the child classes, I get the value but when I change its value, this is only reflected in the child class that has edit the value.

How can I have an attribute that is shared between the two child classes?

```
class BaseData(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_attribute = None


class DataChild1(BaseData):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def print_self(self):
        print(f"Child1 - {self.some_attribute=}")

    def print_parent(self):
        try:
            print(BaseData.some_attribute)   
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        try:
            print(super().some_attribute)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def change(self, value):
        self.some_attribute = value  


class DataChild2(BaseData):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def print_self(self):
        print(f"Child2 - {self.some_attribute=}")

child1 = DataChild1()
child2 = DataChild2()

child1.print_self()
child2.print_self()

child1.change(10)
child1.print_self()
child2.print_self()

child1.print_parent()
```

The code above outputs:

```
Child1 - self.some_attribute=None
Child2 - self.some_attribute=None

Child1 - self.some_attribute=10
Child2 - self.some_attribute=None

type object 'BaseData' has no attribute 'some_attribute'
'super' object has no attribute 'some_attribute'
```

Comment: Unless you're using double underscores in front of your variable names, there's only one namespace for object properties, not a namespace per class hierarchy element. (And it's still one namespace with the underscores, just with a bit of added mangling).

Comment: There's a distinction when you talk about _class_ variables instead of _instance_ variables, but those aren't so useful because they aren't specific to the individual instance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for your reply! Then changing `some_attribute` to be a class variable instead of an instance variable should solve the problem?

Comment: ...but do you really _want_ a class variable? That means there's only one value globally, not one value per object, so changing the value from code in object-A will also change the value seen from code in object-B.

Comment: Anyhow -- if that _is_ what you want, then instead of `self.some_attribute`, refer to `BaseData.some_attribute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable which you are trying to access using the Baseclass i.e some_attribute is not a class variable and hence is showing the particular issue.

Tweaking your code as follows should solve the issue:

```
class BaseData(object):
    some_attribute = None //class variable
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_attribute = None
```